# How to add an automatic filter to a relation with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy 0.5rc, and I'd like to add an automatic filter to a relation, so that every time it tries to fetch records for that relation, it ignores the "remote" ones if they're flagged as "logically_deleted" (a boolean field of the child table)

For example, if an object "parent" has a "children" relation that has
3 records, but one of them is logically deleted, when I query for "Parent" I'd like SQLA to
fetch the parent object with just two children..
How should I do it? By adding an "and" condition to the primaryjoin
parameter of the relation? (e.g. "`Children.parent_id == Parent.id and Children.logically_deleted == False`", but is it correct to write "and" in this way?)

**Edit:**
I managed to do it in this way

```
children = relation("Children", primaryjoin=and_(id == Children.parent_id, Children.logically_deleted==False))
```

but is there a way to use a string as primaryjoin instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The and_() function is the correct way to do logical conjunctions in SQLAlchemy, together with the & operator, but be careful with the latter as it has surprising precedence rules, i.e. higher precedence than comparison operators.

You could also use a string as a primary join with the text() constructor, but that will make your code break with any table aliasing that comes with eagerloading and joins.

For logical deletion, it might be better to map the whole class over a select that ignores deleted values:

```
mapper(Something, select([sometable], sometable.c.deleted == False))
```

Comment: Can this be translated to using the __mapper_args__ ? I mean I'm using declarative.

Comment: I tried to use it in mapper_args, but I get a error message said "mapper() got multiple values for keyword argument 'local_table'". So I'm afraid it's useless.

Answer (score 11):

> but is there a way to use a string as primaryjoin instead?

You can use the following:

```
children = relationship("Children", primaryjoin="and_(Parent.id==Children.parent_id, Children.logically_deleted==False)"
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm only currently developing agains 0.4.something, but here's how I'd suggest it:

```
db.query(Object).filter(Object.first==value).filter(Object.second==False).all()
```

I think that's what you are trying to do, right?

(Note: written in a web browser, not real code!)

Comment: No, I was looking for something automatic.. I'll clarify the question :) Thanks though!

Comment: No worries. I think I understand what you are trying to do, but mainly be reading the code you provided!